# How to get modification date of a symlink in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python, how do I get modification date of a symlink, not the file it points to?

I am using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [`os.lstat()` call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.lstat); it works just like `os.stat()` but doesn't follow symlinks:

```
import os

modification_time = os.lstat(path_to_symlink).st_mtime
```